# How to manage many schemas on one database using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, sql-server-2005, schema

I have one database that has many schemas, one per client. We want to create a web application to be access online by the clients, the application should get the schema on runtime, I think in use `Springframework` and `Hibernate` to access the database. It's possible to use hibernate to make this works? Exist another framework for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate gets all JDBC connections from a connection factory, and this connection factory settings determine the DB schema against which all Hibernate queries/updates are issued. You can configure your application with multiple `SessionFactory` instances, each with a connection factory pointing to a different database schema. Then at runtime, you can pick one the appropriate `SessionFactory` to work with.

A simpler solution would be to run multiple copies of your web application, one for each client.