# Hibernate and Multi-Tenant Database using Schemas in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, playframework

## Background

I am working on a future multi-tenant web application that will need to support thousands of users. The app is being built on top of the Java based Play! MVC Framework using JPA/Hibernate  and postgreSQL.

I watched Guy Naor's talk on  [Writing Multi-tenant Applications in Rails](http://aac2009.confreaks.com/06-feb-2009-14-30-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails-guy-naor.html) in which he talks about a few approaches to multi-tenancy (data isolation decreases as you go down the list):

1. Each customer has a separate database
2. One database with separate schemas and tables (table namespaces) for each customer.
3. One database with 1 set of tables with customer id columns.

I settled on approach #2, where a user id of some sort is parsed out of a request and then used to access that users tablespace. A postgres  `SET search_path TO customer_schema,public` command is given before any query is made to make sure the customer's tables are the target of a query. This is easily done with `@Before` controller annotations in controller methods in *Play!* (this is the approach Guy used in his rails example). The **search_path** in postgres acts exactly like the `$PATH` does in an OS; awesome!

All this sounded great, but I immediately ran into difficulties in implementing it on top of a JDBC/Hibernate/JPA stack because there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically switch schemas at runtime.

## The Problem

#### How do I get either JDBC or Hibernate to support dynamically switching postgres schemas at runtime?

It seems database connections are statically configured by a connection factory (see: [How to manage many schemas on one database using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158820/how-to-manage-many-schemas-on-one-database-using-hibernate)). I have found similar questions with similar answers of using multiple SessionFactorys per user, but since I understand SessionFactorys are heavy weight objects so it's implausible that you could support hundreds of users, let alone thousands of users, going this route.

I haven't committed myself completely to approach #2 above, but I haven't quite abandoned it for approach #3 quite yet either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute the command

```
SET search_path TO customer_schema,public
```

as often as you need to, within the same connection / session / transaction. It is just another command like `SELECT 1;`. More in the [manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html).

Of course, you can also preset the `search_path` per user.

```
ALTER ROLE foo SET search_path=foo, public;
```

If every user or many of them have a schema that matches their user name, you can simply go with the [default setting in postgresql.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html):

```
search_path="$user",public;
```

More ways to set the [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) here:
[How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

Comment: This is the easiest solution since I've now switched to MyBatis and have full control over SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

As of Hibernate 4.0, multi-tenancy is natively supported at the discriminator (customerID), schema, and database level.  See the source code [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/MultiTenancyStrategy.html#SCHEMA), and the unit test [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/multitenancy/schema/SchemaBasedMultiTenancyTest.java).

The difficulty is that, while the unit test's file name is SchemaBasedMultitenancyTest, the actual MultitenancyStrategy used is Database.  I can't find any examples on how to make it work based on schema, but maybe the unit test will be enough to go on...

Comment: As of Hibernate 4.0, multi-tenancy is NOT natively supported at the discriminator level. This is expected in 5.0.

Comment: Kinara, can you provide documentation on this lack of support?  The talk referenced in the OP seems to indicate that it is supported... as well as the [jboss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4623).

Comment: Look at the last para of 16.3 in the same documentation, where it talks about the discriminator approach - "This strategy is not yet implemented in Hibernate as of 4.0 and 4.1. Its support is planned for 5.0."

Comment: @AgileYogi has work on 5.0 started?  I only see 4.3 in github.

Comment: Event in 5.0 Multi-tenancy on Discriminator level is not done yet.

Answer (score 1):

While sharding by schema is common, see [this post](https://influitive.io/our-multi-tenancy-journey-with-postgres-schemas-and-apartment-6ecda151a21f) from the Apartment gem authors covering some drawbacks.

At Citus, we shard via option #3 listed above, and you can read more in our [use-case guide](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v6.2/use_case_guide/multi_tenant.html#) in the Documentation.