# Multiple schema postgres on hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate.
In my web application, users after login have to point to different schema (with same tables) on the same postgres database to make queries.

Is there a method to specify at runtime the schema name, that i have in session ?

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate and Multi-Tenant Database using Schemas in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349267/hibernate-and-multi-tenant-database-using-schemas-in-postgresql)

Comment: Did you search first? Looks like it's already been covered.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't finded this discussion, then the easiest method is, before each query, set the search path? But is good in term of performance with many queries?

Comment: and so I should instantiate an hibernate session  for each schema ... I can somehow pass the schema parameter when executing the query using the same session?