# Connecting to databases with jdbc url with parameter current schema

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc

Connecting to databases with jdbc url `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema`. Can I have multiple schemas in current schema

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349267/hibernate-and-multi-tenant-database-using-schemas-in-postgresql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate and Multi-Tenant Database using Schemas in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349267/hibernate-and-multi-tenant-database-using-schemas-in-postgresql)

Comment: You could just try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to the Postgresql JDBC docs[1], you can provide multiple schemas to the `currentSchema` argument - separated by commas.

This is equivalent of the SQL statement `SET SEARCH_PATH name1,name2,name3`

Example,

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema,public,information_schema
```

However, this only sets the `SEARCH_PATH` to resolve unqualified object names.

1. https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/