# How to query many schemas at the same time in postgres

Tags: postgresql, schema

I have a web app with thousands of schemas (one per user).

I have seen this post

[Hibernate and Multi-Tenant Database using Schemas in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349267/hibernate-and-multi-tenant-database-using-schemas-in-postgresql)

where it is mentioned the search_path approach to querying a particular table in a schema.

I am wondering how to query all the schema at the same time in postgres?

Do I need to implement a python script (for example) to make queries one by one and then gather the results or can I implement that directly in SQL to gather all the queries?

For example if I want a table with userid and number_of_posts and I want to query these fields on each user with a separate schema, how would i write that in SQL? I don't see how to change the search path in a unique query automatically.

Is there a command in postgres to list all the existing schemas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata; However, I can not imagine why you would need one schema per user. A data model like that creates imho a huge amount of problems and this is just one of them.

Comment: thank you. It's a common database architecture for managing users data when you need data isolation from what i've read on the web...

Comment: Different source, different opinion... We handle millions of users and by law they are not allowed to see each others data. But different schemas would be the worst possible solution. A simpel "WHERE user = ?" fixes the problem.

Comment: you seem experienced from what i read in your profile...what would you suggest? your where user=? only deals with queries right?

Comment: Yes, the access issue to data is solved in the SQL you use for all your CRUD operations. And you don't need DDL anymore when a new customers comes in, you don't have to create a schema, nor tables, indexes and other stuff for this user.

Comment: Isnt there some isolation regulations stricter than others and that would be the reason to use schemas on a large scale? 
you think putting all the users in a big table is good enough? 
what about scale? normalization, indexing, partitioning and finetuning pg settings (pgbounce, buffer, cache, max connection) is enough ?